# Checking the parameters of a Stored Procedure in Mariadb

Tags: mariadb

This is a query where a Ternary relationship is being modelled, but the main query is about how to check
the parameters of a Stored Procedure.

```
-- Each piece of Work presented at an Event may have upto 5 (Person who are) Discussants.
-- This is a Ternary Relationship being modelled as multiple Binary Relationships.

CREATE TABLE Work(id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
                  Work_Title VARCHAR(500),
          CONSTRAINT Work_PK PRIMARY KEY (id));
      
CREATE TABLE Event(id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
                   Event_Title VARCHAR(100),
                   CONSTRAINT Event_PK PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE Work_at_Event(id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
                   Work_id INT NULL,
               Event_id INT NULL,
               CONSTRAINT Work_at_Event_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
               CONSTRAINT Work_at_Event_Candidate_Key UNIQUE (Work_id,Event_id));
                    -- (Work_id,Event_id) is a Candidate key    

CREATE TABLE Person(id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENt,
                First_Name VARCHAR(100),
        Last_Name VARCHAR(100),
                CONSTRAINT Person_PK PRIMARY KEY (id));         

CREATE TABLE Discussant(id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
           Work_at_Event_id INT,      
           Person_id INT,
       CONSTRAINT Discussant_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
       CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (Work_at_Event_id) REFERENCES Work_at_Event(id),
       CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (Person_id) REFERENCES Person(id),
       CONSTRAINT Discussant_Candidate_Key UNIQUE (Work_at_Event_id,Person_id));
       );
   
Stored Procedure :- Discussant_Add

DELIMITER //                      
CREATE PROCEDURE Discussant_Add (_Work_at_Event_Id INT,_Discussant_1 INT,_Discussant_2 INT,_Discussant_3 INT,_Discussant_4 INT,_Discussant_5 INT)

-- How do I check that _Discussant_1,...,_Discussant_5 are all Distinct and NOT NULL?
-- Here is my attempt.I am checking for NOT NULL, I don't know how to check if they are all Distinct.
-- See below for the answer to the above query.
BEGIN
    IF NOT NULL Discussant_1
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_1);
    ENDIF;
    IF NOT NULL Discussant_2
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_2);
    ENDIF;
    IF NOT NULL Discussant_3
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_3);
    ENDIF;
    IF NOT NULL Discussant_4
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_4);
    ENDIF;
    IF NOT NULL Discussant_5
INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_5);
ENDIF;
END//
DELIMITER ;

-- Inspired by the answer by nbk I have rewritten the function Discussant_Add.

DELIMITER //                      

CREATE PROCEDURE Discussant_Add (_Work_at_Event_Id INT,_Discussant_1 INT,_Discussant_2 INT,_Discussant_3 INT,_Discussant_4 INT,_Discussant_5 INT)

BEGIN
    IF NOT NULL _Discussant_1 and _Discussant_1 NOT IN (_Discussant_2,_Discussant_3,_Discussant_4,_Discussant_5)
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (NULL,_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_1);
ENDIF;

    IF NOT NULL _Discussant_2 and _Discussant_2 NOT IN (_Discussant_3,_Discussant_4,_Discussant_5)
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (NULL,_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_2);
    ENDIF;

    IF NOT NULL _Discussant_3 and _Discussant_3 NOT IN (_Discussant_4,_Discussant_5)
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (NULL,_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_3);
    ENDIF;

    IF NOT NULL _Discussant_4 and _Discussant_4 NOT IN (_Discussant_5)
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (NULL,_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_4);
    ENDIF;

    IF NOT NULL _Discussant_5
    INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (NULL,_Work_at_Event_id,_Discussant_5);
    ENDIF;
END//
DELIMITER ;


-- How do I write a function similar to Discussant_Add, which can 1. Read the current Disussants and
-- 2. Update the Discussants. 1. Is easy I will SELECT all Person which are in the Discussant table which correspond to the _Work_at_Event_id, but how to I update them ? How do I check that some Discussants exist, some are to be deleted and some are to be added and then do
-- the needful ? 3.The end goal is to ensure that on updating there are no more than 5 Discussants for each piece of _Work_at_Event_id.

Stored Procedure :- Discussant_Update

CREATE PROCEDURE Discussant_Update (_Work_at_Event_id INT,_Discussant_1 INT,_Discussant_2 INT,_Discussant_3 INT,_Discussant_4 INT,_Discussant_5 INT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks somewhat unfamiliar to me

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Discussant_Update`(_Work_at_Event_id INT,_Discussant_1 INT,_Discussant_2 INT,_Discussant_3 INT,_Discussant_4 INT,_Discussant_5 INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE n  INT;
    SET n = 0;
    DELETE FROM Discussant WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM Discussant) d WHERE Work_at_Event_id = _Work_at_Event_id AND Person_id NOT IN (_Discussant_1,_Discussant_2,_Discussant_3,_Discussant_4,_Discussant_5));
    loop_Discussant:  LOOP
        IF  n =  6 THEN 
            LEAVE  loop_Discussant;
        END  IF;
        CASE n
            WHEN  1 THEN
               SET @Discussant = _Discussant_1;
            WHEN 2 THEN
               SET @Discussant = _Discussant_2;
            WHEN 3 THEN
               SET @Discussant = _Discussant_3;
            WHEN 4 THEN
               SET @Discussant = _Discussant_4;               
            ELSE
               SET @Discussant = _Discussant_5;
        END CASE;
        
        IF @Discussant IS NOT NULL  THEN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Discussant WHERE Work_at_Event_id = _Work_at_Event_id AND Person_id = @Discussant) THEN
                INSERT INTO Discussant VALUES (NULL,_Work_at_Event_id,@Discussant);
            END IF;
       END IF;
        SET  n = n + 1;
    END LOOP;

    SELECT * FROM Discussant;
END
```

This procedure would delete first all rows that are not in the new list and then add only the new one.

As you can see, i shortened the code a little bit, so that i must only correct 1 code and not 5.

Comment: My apologies for the delay in the reply. Your reply is wonderful because I don't need 2 separate functions - Discussant_Add and Discussant_Update. Discussant_Update alone can Add as well as Update the Discussant_Table. However,Inspired by your answer I have rewritten Discussant_Add. Discussant_Add has a small advantage that it does not hit the database and should be faster than Discussant_Update.

Comment: this actually verry fast, because of indexes and the smal number, but i am gad it works for you

Comment: ok and thank you once again!